# Why won't my Cocos2d test app fire "touchesBegan" events?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In my app delegate, I made sure I have the line:

```
    [glView setMultipleTouchEnabled: YES];
```

And I have a simple layer meant only to figure out how multi touch works. The .mm file looks like:

```
#import "TestLayer.h"

@implementation TestLayer
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) draw{
     [super draw];
    glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.35);
    glLineWidth(6.0f);
    ccDrawCircle(ccp(500,500), 250,CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360), 60,YES);

}

-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"got some touches");
}

-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"some touches moved.");
}

-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"a touch began");
    return FALSE;
}
@end
```

When I touch the screen, I always see "a touch began", but no matter how I touch it (simulator or actual device), I never see "some touches moved" or "got some touches".

Is there something further I need to do to make multi touch work?

Specifically, I'm just trying to do basic pinch-to-zoom functionality...  I heard there is some sort of gesture recognizer for iPhone...does it work for Coco2ds?  Would it work even if I can't get simple multi touch events to fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIGestureRecognizers` absolutely work for Cocos2D, I personally used them, you just need to add them to the correct view by using:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:myGestureRecognizer];
```

Regarding your touches, I guess you enabled them for the scene you are working in?

```
scene.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

In any case you shouldn't use the `addTargetDelegate` method, take a look [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/17540)

Comment: Are `UIGestureRecognizers` work on a `CCSprite`? [CCGestureRecognizers](https://github.com/jerrodputman/CCKit/tree/master/CCKit)

Comment: I had no idea that the addTargetDelegate was for single touches only. Thanks!

Comment: What about when I want to have multiple layers with different priority? The target delegate seems to be useful for that...

Comment: Specifically, now that I'm using isTouchEnabled, my first layer is passing all the touches it should be swallowing down to the next layer.

Answer (score 1):

add `self.isTouchEnabled = YES;` to your init

and for the gesture recognizers look at the other answer